# List won't work with columns in css nor with floats

Tags: html, css

I'm working with my personal page. 
 I want to make columns out of the lists .
How can i do this . 
 I tried grid's  and columns and it don't work .  For some reason i'm thinking a web kit. Any suggestions ?  I also tried to float margin , width, position , left and so forth .  I'm officially  stuck .  I did use a max with of 960 pixels.   Was that the wrong way to go ?  I also centered aligned my page as well? Was that wrong as well ?

```css
/*body  styles*/
body, html{background-color:#4B88A2;}
.grid-container{display:grid;
 /*grid grid-template: 1fr repeat(11,10px 1fr);*/
 grid-template-columns:[left-sidebar-start] 1fr 10px 1fr[right-sidebar-end]
  10px
  [main-area-start]1fr reapeat(11,[gutter] 10px [row]1fr[main-area-end])
  10px
  [right-sidebar-start] 1fr 10px 1fr [right-sidebar-end];
grid-template-rows: [header-start] 1fr[header-end]
 10px
 [main-start] 1fr[main-end]
 [footer-start]1fr[footer-end]
}
/*.content-wrap{max-width:950px;
 margin: 0 auto;overflow:auto;padding:60px 50px; }*/
 
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/*headers*/
h1,h2{font-family:'lobster', cursive;
 font-size:40px;font-weight: 400;}
h1{font-size:80px;}
h3{margin:0;}

header{text-align: center;}
header{padding-top: 60px;position:relative; }



h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  
 font-size: 40px;}
/*navigation*/
.nav{text-align:center;
position:fixed; top:0;width:100%;margin:0px; }
 
.nav a{display:inline-block;
 padding:15px 20px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:700;
}
.footer{position: fixed;
left:0; bottom:0;width:100%;
 text-align:center; background-color:slategray;
 display:block;}

/*columns*/
.column1{float:left;
width:900px;
marging:10px;}

.column2{float:left;
width:300px;margin:10px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/multiColumnTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    </head>
   

  <body>
   
   <header role="banner">
    
       <nav role="navigation">  
 <div class="nav">
  <a href="larry main.html">Home</a>
 <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#">Downloads</a>
 <!-- Right navigation-->
   
   </div>
    </nav>
    
    
    <div class="content-wrap">
  <h1>Larry J Designs</h1>
     <h2>Beginner web designer/ artist</h2>
 <div class="about" id="about-me">
  <p><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="stock" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></p>
  <p> Hello, I'm Larry J  , I currently live in the DC Metro area , i also  love working on art in my spare time. 
  As a teen  in high I use to love to draw and build websites ,  
  Currently, I work a full time job like most , however in my spare time I love working on learning web design and drawing .
    Life has a long road to success , but on the road there are  that you have to learn to get to the next level .  Here are  mines bellow :</p></div></div> 
 
 </header>
 
 
 

   <main role="main">
  
    <section><!--my skill-->
  <div class="content-wrap">
    
   <div class="column1">
  <h3>Skills in progress</h3>
   <ul>
   
   <li>HTML</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>Java script</li>
    <li>J query</li>
   </ul></div>
  
   
   <div class="column2">
 <h3>Next Skills to learn</h3>
    <ul>
   <li>Photoshop</li>
   <li>Illustrator</li>
   <li>Logo design</li>
   <li>Graphic arts</li>
   <li>T-shirt Design</li>
    </ul>
    </div></section>
  </main>
   <!--my skill-->
   
  
    
   <!--skills list end-->
  
  <!--container end--> 
  <div class="footer">
      <p>&copy;Larry J designs </p>
</div>

 
   
  </body>
```

`.

Comment: Please help us help you by improving the formatting of your code. Better still reduce it to a [MCVE] containing just enough code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your `column1` and `column2` css with `display: inline-block` instead of `float` and it worked. I also made the `width` percentual.

```css
/*body  styles*/
body, html{background-color:#4B88A2;}
.grid-container{display:grid;
 /*grid grid-template: 1fr repeat(11,10px 1fr);*/
 grid-template-columns:[left-sidebar-start] 1fr 10px 1fr[right-sidebar-end]
  10px
  [main-area-start]1fr reapeat(11,[gutter] 10px [row]1fr[main-area-end])
  10px
  [right-sidebar-start] 1fr 10px 1fr [right-sidebar-end];
grid-template-rows: [header-start] 1fr[header-end]
 10px
 [main-start] 1fr[main-end]
 [footer-start]1fr[footer-end]
}
/*.content-wrap{max-width:950px;
 margin: 0 auto;overflow:auto;padding:60px 50px; }*/
 
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/*headers*/
h1,h2{font-family:'lobster', cursive;
 font-size:40px;font-weight: 400;}
h1{font-size:80px;}
h3{margin:0;}

header{text-align: center;}
header{padding-top: 60px;position:relative; }



h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  
 font-size: 40px;}
/*navigation*/
.nav{text-align:center;
position:fixed; top:0;width:100%;margin:0px; }
 
.nav a{display:inline-block;
 padding:15px 20px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:700;
}
.footer{position: fixed;
left:0; bottom:0;width:100%;
 text-align:center; background-color:slategray;
 display:block;}

/*columns*/
.column1{
display: inline-block;
width:calc(60%-10);
margin:10px;
vertical-align: top;
}

.column2{
display: inline-block;
width:calc(30%-10);
margin:10px;
vertical-align: top;
font-size: 
}
.content-wrap {

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/multiColumnTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    </head>
   

  <body>
   
   <header role="banner">
    
       <nav role="navigation">  
 <div class="nav">
  <a href="larry main.html">Home</a>
 <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#">Downloads</a>
 <!-- Right navigation-->
   
   </div>
    </nav>
    
    
    <div class="content-wrap">
  <h1>Larry J Designs</h1>
     <h2>Beginner web designer/ artist</h2>
 <div class="about" id="about-me">
  <p><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="stock" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></p>
  <p> Hello, I'm Larry J  , I currently live in the DC Metro area , i also  love working on art in my spare time. 
  As a teen  in high I use to love to draw and build websites ,  
  Currently, I work a full time job like most , however in my spare time I love working on learning web design and drawing .
    Life has a long road to success , but on the road there are  that you have to learn to get to the next level .  Here are  mines bellow :</p></div></div> 
 
 </header>
 
 
 

   <main role="main">
  
    <section><!--my skill-->
  <div class="content-wrap">
    
   <div class="column1">
  <h3>Skills in progress</h3>
   <ul>
   
   <li>HTML</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>Java script</li>
    <li>J query</li>
   </ul></div>
  
   
   <div class="column2">
 <h3>Next Skills to learn</h3>
    <ul>
   <li>Photoshop</li>
   <li>Illustrator</li>
   <li>Logo design</li>
   <li>Graphic arts</li>
   <li>T-shirt Design</li>
    </ul>
    </div></section>
  </main>
   <!--my skill-->
   
  
    
   <!--skills list end-->
  
  <!--container end--> 
  <div class="footer">
      <p>&copy;Larry J designs </p>
</div>

 
   
  </body>
```

Also, there was a typo on the `margin` property name on the line `58` in your css code.

Hope it helps,

best

Comment: Thanks alot .  How do i  center it ?